# How to solve Chrome extension cannot find DOM event when fired on click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that fires on a button click, the extension still can't access DOM elements, even though the page has clearly loaded.

I've seen other posts say it is because the elements are being created dynamically but not in my case.

The only thing that works is to wrap my debugTools.js in a timeout and fire it after 800 or so milliseconds.

The code inside debugTools.js is the part not working. I don't understand why is says "theWrapper" is undefined even if I wait 10 minutes before clicking my button which executes the code.

wrapper definitely exists on the page I navigate to before clicking my button. It is there in regular HMTL code. Not dynamically generated. I feel posting this page code would just confuse the question.

```
// manifest.json
{
    "name": "Jams Dev Tools",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Provides dev tools",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    ... // icons are included here

    "manifest_version": 2,

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "debugTools.css",
        "debugTools.js"
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

```
// debugTools.js

var theWrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
console.log(theWrapper.style.width);
```

```
// injectFiles.js

if(document.getElementById("debugJs") == undefined) {
    // Inject Css
    var debugJs = document.createElement('script');
    var theSource = chrome.extension.getURL("debugTools.js");
    debugJs.setAttribute( 'src', theSource );
    debugJs.id = "debugJs";
    document.body.appendChild(debugJs);
}
```

```
// background.js

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'injectFiles.js'
    });
});
```

Comment: Please indicate which element cannot be accessed, in which line of code, what is the exact error message, does this happen on all pages or a specific page. Judging by the code you've posted you seem to assume #wrapper is present on the page which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Appolgies. The code inside debugTools.js cannot access DOM elements unless inside a delay. The part I don't understand is why that occurs even if I wait 20 minutes before pushing my button which then runs the code.

Comment: The posted fragment(?) of debugTools.js seems to assume #wrapper is present on the page which is not guaranteed because you didn't show how it's created.

Comment: wrapper is on the web page i navigate to before clicking the button

Comment: So does the problem occur on a specific page? Or do you expect the #wrapper element to be present on all pages in the internet?

Comment: I am building dev tools for internal use on banners we make, wrapper exists in all of them.

Comment: As i said, the code works if I delay the initialisation of the code with a setTimeout so wrapper definately exists on the page.

Comment: How did you verify the element exists before the script runs? Also, is the banner in an iframe?

Comment: Ok, so imagine I am on this page, the page has been loaded for 5 minutes. Then I click my chrome extension http://gravitystaging.com/uploadarea/test/testBanner/ As you can see wrapper is there in the DOM. I can also access the DOM after a small delay as I said. That is a delay on the buttons execution.

Comment: Here is an image of the console log http://gravitystaging.com/uploadarea/test/testBanner/stackImage.jpg You can see from this image that the first thing logged to the console is actually a javascript object that exists within the page, so i can access javascript from the page but not the DOM as with the second console log there.

Comment: The screenshot shows the error in a code that's not present in the question so I doubt the question can be answered without a better [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was one of those times when you just can't see the wood for the trees. Thank you all for any help you have given. It turns out I'm an idiot. The problem can be summed up with the below snippet.

```
debug();

var theWrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

function debug() {
   console.log(theWrapper.width);
}
```